# How do I access members of this structure in C?

Tags: c

I'm working with this structure in C:

```
/** This structure describes an Internet host address. */
typedef struct pj_hostent
{
    char    *h_name;        /**< The official name of the host. */
    char   **h_aliases;     /**< Aliases list. */
    int      h_addrtype;    /**< Host address type. */
    int      h_length;      /**< Length of address. */
    char   **h_addr_list;   /**< List of addresses. */
} pj_hostent;
```

I can access the `h_name` part of the structure fine like this:

```
strcpy(test1, he->h_name); // copy part of struct into char[] array
```

and it contains a meaningful "sip2" value.  However, when I try to access the elements of `h_addr_list` like this:

```
strcpy(test1, he->h_addr_list[0]);
```

I get meaningless jibberish.

What's the correct way in C to access values like this?

Comment: did you initialize that value or allocate for it.

Comment: If the structure has been allocated and initialized in the usual manner your suggested syntax is fine.

Comment: How do you interpret the contents of `test1`?

Comment: Did you check `h_length` first ? If `h_length == 0` then there will be no valid entries in `h_addr_list`.

Comment: I'm passing this structure to an API method that then fills it. I'm trying to find out what values are now in this structure.

Comment: Is the address list really an array of pointers to 'generic data'?  The sockets API just predates the widespread use of 'void *'.  And which API on which platform are you using to populate the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing it correctly. That field really does contain gibberish.

Answer (score 4):

`h_addr_list[0]` is not a string, it is a `pj_in_addr`, which is a 32-bit integer which is not null terminated.

`printf()` it with `%d` or `%x`, not `%s`.

See [PJLIB Reference: Network Address Resolution](http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/group__pj__addr__resolve.htm) for an example of use.

Comment: This is a useful answer. The asker is having a problem with APIs, not with C; perhaps the question should be edited to reflect this. To add to this answer: you could also use the inet_ntoa or inet_ntop functions to convert an in_addr to a string.

Comment: @tcovo: I am having problems with APIs *and* with C (not to mention problems using a Mac for the first time in 20 years). I'm about to ask another question about taking an IP address given to me as an `unsigned int` and converting it to an `NSString` like "192.10.56.102", which I'm guessing the two functions you mentioned are good for.

Answer (score 1):

Just because it is declared as a `char**` does **NOT** mean that it is an array of strings.

It may be a pointer to a byte-buffer of unknown format. (ie. jibberish)

You should check any available documentation or other source code for details of exactly what h_addr_list is, and how it should be interpreted.

Comment: +1. Read documentation instead of assuming/guessing what an API gives you - if documentation is non existing, you'll have to resort to source code/examples.

Answer (score 0):

The struct only contains a pointer. You need to allocate some storage for that pointer to point *at* before you can use it. As it is, the pointer almost certainly just contains a (more or less) random value. When you use that as a target in your call to `strcpy`, you're overwriting that random memory location -- which can and will lead to major problems elsewhere.

`h_addr_list` is pretty much the same way -- it's just a pointer to a pointer. That'll (normally) be used to refer to an array of strings, but something has to allocate that array of strings before it can be put to any meaningful use. Given the similarity to a `hostent` structure, along with this structure there's presumably some analog to (or wrapper around) `gethostbyname` and/or `gethostbyaddress` that initializes this. In the case of the wrapper (which I'd judge the more likely of the two), it probably gets the correct data in a `hostent`, and then copies data from the `hostent` to this structure.

Answer (score 0):

A short Example that does work. Remember that allocating for the struct does not allocate for the pointer.

```
typedef struct pj_hostent
{
    char    *h_name;        /**< The official name of the host. */
    char   **h_aliases;     /**< Aliases list. */
    int      h_addrtype;    /**< Host address type. */
    int      h_length;      /**< Length of address. */
    char   **h_addr_list;   /**< List of addresses. */
} pj_hostent;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* s[]= {"this","is","couple of words"};
    pj_hostent hst = {"high",s,3,4,s };
    char  buff[255] = {};
    //Access as a local initialized struct
    strcpy(buff,hst.h_addr_list[0]);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    pj_hostent * he = & hst; 
    //Access as a pointer 
    strcpy(buff,he->h_addr_list[0]);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    gets(buff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never initialized/allocated memory for those pointers, you would get jibberish and/or segmentation faults because they are pointing to random points in memory.

Answer (score -1):

`strcpy` assumes that you have already allocated memory to the character pointer. So, probably, the pointer is still having a `NULL` value.

Answer (score -4):

struct elements are accessed with the dot operator

```
strcpy(test1, he.h_addr_list[0]);
```

elements of structs that are "pointed" to are accessed with the -> operator

```
strcpy(test1, he->h_addr_list->[0]);
```

If you're getting gibberish, then either test1 isn't big enough, h_addr_list isn't pointing to an array of char*, or the first element of the array is actually gibberish.

Comment: It wouldn't compile if he was doing this wrongly. His example uses an arrow for the field that does work.

Comment: I'm doing this in XCode, and using the dot operator generates an error "Request for member 'h_addr_list' in something not a structure or union"